# sdk for morpho (safran) biometric scanner device

Tags: c#, .net, device, biometrics, image-scanner

i have one safran device and its driver software. but i want to control it using c#. but i am unable to locate the SDK for this morpho biometric scanner. can anyone help me, so that i can make an home application with help of that.

i have tried with following code

```
using Morpho;
using MorphoAPI_1_0;
using MorphoSdkLiteDotNetWrapper;

Morpho.MorphoSmart.MorphoSmartDevice mSmtDev = new Morpho.MorphoSmart.MorphoSmartDevice();
```

but this give following error
Could not load file or assembly 'Morpho.MorphoSmart.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Hi there, Did you come right with your question? I might be able to assist

Comment: Hi @Jaques, please help me.

Comment: Before I can help you, can you first tell me what MSO (reader) are you using? And what are you using it for? And can you send me contact information?

Comment: @chitrakshbairathee, you still need the SDK?

Comment: Do you have the SDK for windows platform?? @Frederik Moller

Comment: @chitrakshbairathee I am facing the same issue. can you please let me know how did you fix this issue. I have the SDk,OS windows 8.1, and VS 2017.

Comment: can you provide where you get dll file and there documentation. i search almost in internet. i coud'nt get proper result .did you solve that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy all of the dll file located in dll folder into the folder where your application will be released, according to your target machine architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you should have two MorphoSmart libraries. One for x64, one for x86. I was using the x64 one in AnyCpu configuration and I was getting the same error. After switching to the x86 dll it worked fine (with AnyCpu configuration and a x64 operating system).